# YML config always truthy in Grails

Tags: grails

I am trying to get some YML config value and I can confirm that I'm getting the correct value. The problem is when I tried to do some `if statement`, it looks like the value is `always true` even it's `suppose to be false`. My config is look like this:

```
locale
  useLangSubDir: false
```

And code is:

```
def language = ""
def useLangSubDir = grailsApplication.config.getProperty("ciab.locale.useLangSubDir")

if (useLangSubDir) { // always true
  language = "/" + WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().getCurrentRequest().activeLocale
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [default config](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#config) property type (from `getProperty` is String)

So you are getting the String `"false"` which in Groovy truth is `true` as it is not null, or empty.

You need to do:

```
def useLangSubDir = grailsApplication.config.getProperty("ciab.locale.useLangSubDir", Boolean, false)
```

To get it as a `Boolean` (with a default of `false`)